# Export first few pages of Doc to PDF using LibreOffice

Tags: macos, pdf, openoffice, libreoffice

I have been using LibreOffice in my rails app to convert my Doc to PDF using the command

> /Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice --headless
>   --convert-to pdf --outdir destination_path source_path/*.doc

in my rails app.

I planned to convert the entire Doc to PDF and display only a few pages of PDF, but it was not efficient to store the entire PDF only for preview purposes.

Is there a LibreOffice command or any other command that can help me export only the first few pages of Doc to PDF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to do that conversion some time ago, and I used `unoconv` in this way:

```
$ unoconv -f pdf -e PageRange=1-3 file.doc
```

It will convert to pdf only the first three pages.

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: As per this code, the doc is converted and saved in the same folder. How can i change the destination folder?

Comment: Try this option: `-o /path/to/folder/`